# NATIVE access to Facebook Events and Birthdays calendar

Tags: facebook

fbcal does a great job of exporting my Facebook events and birthdays to an accessible calendar I can subscribe to in Google Calendar, iCal, etc.  However, it seems silly to require a third party app to do this.

How can I directly access my event information on Facebook as a calendar?

Answer (score 1):

You can export events by using the Export Events link at the bottom your Events page.  This will bring up a dialog with a URL you can use to add the calendar to other apps.

There are several third-party apps to export birthdays, but I don't know of a native way.

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/152652248136178/):

> **How do I export my events or friends' birthdays?**
>
> You can export events and friends' birthdays from Facebook into
>   calendar programs like Apple iCal, Microsoft Outlook and Google
>   Calendar. To export all upcoming events or birthdays at once:
>
> 1. Click `Events` on the left side of your homepage.
> 2. At the bottom right, below **Events Happening This Week**, click **Upcoming Events** to export all upcoming events. Click **Birthdays** to
>      export all upcoming birthdays.
>
> To export an individual upcoming event:
>
> 1. Go to the event you'd like to export and click <kbd>...</kbd> > `Export Event`.
> 2. Select whether to save the event to your computer or send it in an email.
> 3. Click **Export**.